# Setting up a sublime symlink in Mac OS X while running pyenv

Tags: macos, bash, symbolic-link, sublime-text-2

There are a lot of SO and links on how to setup a symlink so you can run sublime from the command line. But I'm running pyenv and it seems to have its own ~/.bash_profile as the real one doesn't have any export PATH= in it.

Basically,

1) I have no trouble executing `~/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl .` It opens sublime fine.

2) I run `ln -s <above path> /usr/local/bin` and don't get any error

3) when I do echo $PATH I see that `/usr/local/bin` is listed

4) when I type `subl .` or `subl <some file>` I get a bash error that subl is not a command.

5) When I call `open ~/.bash_profile` is just has two pyenv related execute commands

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Nothing about `export PATH=` as I expected.

How can I create the `subl` symlink so I can call sublime from the command-line? My ultimate goal is to set it as my command-line git editor.

Also, I tried calling `source ~/.bash_profile` a few times and when I go back and do `echo $PATH` it keeps adding the first directory again and again, so it seems pyenv is rerouting to its own local bash_profile which does have the export PATH=(..)$PATH and keeps repeating the thing. How can I edit this? I can't seem to get it at because the `echo` command gets routed through pyenv so I see $PATH but it's a different bash_profile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your `.bash_profile`. Your symlink command is incorrect — you need to specify the name of the symlink, not just the directory it's in:

```
sudo ln -s ~/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Comment: When I try that it says `/usr/local/bin/subl` No such file or directory

Comment: @river_jones What is the output of `ls -l /usr/local/bin/subl`?

Comment: Sorry, I was being dumb, I was typing `ls -s` instead of `ln -s`, thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @river_jones no problem, glad to help!